# Delphi XE3: how to detect CellClick and DblClick on grid

Tags: delphi, datagrid

I have a problem with detecting which mouse event occurred. I want to show a description when the user clicks the mouse once, and do other things when the user double clicks.

I tried use TTimer, but that doesn't work. Double click show message and do procedure "DoSomething".

**I use TDBGrid and OnCellClick and OnDblClick.**

Sample code:

```
procedure timerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer.Enabled := false;
  fFlagaDblClick := false;
  ShowMessage('sample message');
end;

procedure gridListCellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
    timer.Enabled := true;
    fFlagaDblClick := False;
end;

procedure gridListDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   timer.Enabled := false;
   fFlagaDblClick := True;
   DoSomething;
end;
```

Comment: What grid are you talking about? TStringGrid has both OnClick and OnDblClick events

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kudos on including code, note that it is considered bad form to put `please`, `thanks`, `TIA` etc in your question. Also it's always best to be specific.... List the exact flavor of grid that you're using.

Answer (score 2):

The Delphi Grids have `OnClick` and `OnDblClick` event handlers.

[image]

The only problem is that these event handlers do not pass the currently selected cell as an argument.
However with a little bit of code this is easily remedied.

```
procedure TForm24.GridDisassemblyDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Current row is '+IntToStr(GridDisassembly.Row)
              +'; current column is: '+IntToStr(GridDisassembly.Col));
end;
```

In order for the currently selected column to be anything other than `0` xGrid.Options must not have `goRowSelect` enabled.

Comment: I use TDBGrid and OnCellClick and OnDblClick.

Comment: @anna, you need to put that info in the question :-) not in a comment. Without **details** questions cannot be answered properly.

Comment: I'm new here. Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solution:
In procedure gridListDblClick I disable event OnCellClik and enable in gridListEnter.
It's working.

```
procedure timerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer.Enabled := false;
  fFlagaDblClick := false;
  ShowMessage('sample message');
end;

procedure gridListCellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
    timer.Enabled := true;
    fFlagaDblClick := False;
end;

procedure gridListDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   gridList.OnCellClick := nil;
   timer.Enabled := false;
   fFlagaDblClick := True;
   DoSomething;
end;

procedure gridListEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  gridList.OnCellClick := gridListCellClick;
end;
```